# UNIX_TIMESTAMP() repeated more than once in MySQL request

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I need to get current date (and time 00:00:00) epoch timestamp in MySQL request. I want to do this with math expression: (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() % 86400)).

But this calls UNIX_TIMESTAMP() more than once; so the question is - is there a possibility that two UNIX_TIMESTAMP() functions return different time? What is the workaround in this case?

Or maybe MySQL executes UNIX_TIMESTAMP() once, and replaces all other calls with current timestamp and no workaround needed?

Comment: I can return two different timestamps when on the cusp of the end of a second

Comment: ok, what is the workaround? without procedures. I need to get timestamp representing current date and time 00:00:00.

Comment: @EdHeal, can it?  `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), SLEEP(5), UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, which will return the start time of the current query.

This isn't explicitly documented — the docs make general reference to the stability of "Functions that return the current date or time ..." — but it is so.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now), because `NOW()` returns the timestamp when the statement began to execute, so it would behave consistently across multiple calls in the same statement.

> NOW() returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the
>   statement began to execute. (Within a stored function or trigger,
>   NOW() returns the time at which the function or triggering statement
>   began to execute.)

Comment: So I can use UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) % 86400)?

Comment: Not necessary.  UNIX_TIMESTAMP with no arguments is also fixed for a transaction.

Comment: @pilcrow so I can use expression I first defined in my post, and it will be always correct?

Comment: @deselect, yes.  And I misspoke above.  I meant "fixed for the current query", _not_ for the current transaction.  I've put that into another answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @ut:=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), (@ut - (@ut % 86400)) AS ep;
```